# IF (CASE) THEN SELECT STATEMENT in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a query in oracle that looks like this

```
DECLARE
   my_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(table.column1) INTO my_count FROM table;

  IF my_count > 2 THEN
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column2 = 'ABC';
  ELSE
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column2 != 'ABC';
  END IF;
END;
```

Is there any answer that works the same?

Comment: I want to use it as a filter in ETL tools

Comment: I would not recommend using "count" as a variable name (in any SQL related system)

Comment: Also don't use `table` as a table name. Your initial query (`SELECT COUNT(table.column1) INTO my_count FROM table;`) most likely needs a `WHERE` clause to determine the value for `my_count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
with temp (cnt) as
  (select count(column1) from table)
select * from table cross join temp where column2 = 'ABC' and cnt > 2
union all
select * from table cross join temp where column2 <> 'ABC' and cnt <= 2;
```

---

Demo, based on Scott's sample schema: there are 4 clerks and - as that number is greater than 2, I'll fetch employees who work in department 10 (i.e. query in line #3 will be executed):

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp where job = 'CLERK';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

SQL> select ename from emp where deptno = 10;

ENAME
----------
CLARK
KING
MILLER
    
SQL> with temp (cnt) as
  2    (select count(*) from emp where job = 'CLERK')
  3  select ename from emp cross join temp where deptno = 10 and cnt > 2
  4  union all
  5  select ename from emp cross join temp where deptno <>10 and cnt <= 2;

ENAME
----------
CLARK             --> right; here they are
KING
MILLER
```

As there's only one president, count is lower than 2 and query will return results from line #5:

```
SQL> with temp (cnt) as
  2    (select count(*) from emp where job = 'PRESIDENT')
  3  select ename from emp cross join temp where deptno = 10 and cnt > 2
  4  union all
  5  select ename from emp cross join temp where deptno <>10 and cnt <= 2;

ENAME
----------
BLAKE
SCOTT
TURNER
ADAMS
JAMES
FORD
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear what you realy want to do, but your Select commands within IF ...END IF; are wrong. In pl/sql you can not do it that way. You should Select ... Into something like you did with the first Select or use it as, for instance, SYS_REFCURSOR (maybe that is the "query" you want to create).
If we use some sample data like here:

```sql
Select * From test_tbl;
      COL1 COL2
---------- ----
         1 ABC
         2 DEF
         3 ABC
         4 DEF
         5 ABC
```

... then maybe the code below could help you get your query (cursor)

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    m_col1    Number(3);
    m_col2    VarChar(3);
    my_count  Number;
    c         SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO my_count FROM test_tbl;
  IF my_count > 2 THEN
     OPEN c for SELECT * FROM test_tbl WHERE COL2 = 'ABC';
  ELSE
     OPEN c for SELECT * FROM test_tbl WHERE COL2 != 'ABC';
  END IF;
  Loop
      FETCH c Into m_col1, m_col2;
      EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
      dbms_output.put_line(m_col1 || ' --> ' || m_col2);
  End Loop;
  CLOSE c;
END;
/*  R e s u l t :
1 --> ABC
3 --> ABC
5 --> ABC   */
```

Or maybe just SQL...

```sql
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM (  Select  Count(Distinct COL1) OVER() "CNT", COL1, COL2 
        From    test_tbl
     )
WHERE (CNT > 2 And COL2 = 'ABC') OR 
      (CNT <= 2 And COL2 != 'ABC')
/*  R e s u l t :
      COL1 COL2
---------- ----
         1 ABC
         3 ABC
         5 ABC    */
```